# How to bind ListView controls to ComboBox ItemSource

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I need to add two `ListView` controls to `ComboBox` items, but it is displaying the listview items instead of the listview name.

```
listView = new ListView();
ObservableCollection<String> list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
list.Add("1");
list.Add("2");      
listView.ItemsSource = list;

listView2 = new ListView();
ObservableCollection<String> list12 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
list12.Add("11");
list12.Add("12");
listView2.ItemsSource = list12;

combobox.Items.Add(listView);
combobox.Items.Add(listView12);

private void combobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var combobox = sender as ComboBox;
   if(combobox.SelectedIndex == 0)
      combobox.ItemsSource = listView;
   else
      combobox.ItemsSource = listView12;
}
```

Here is my Xaml code

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="4" x:Name="combobox" SelectionChanged="combobox_SelectionChanged" />
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a Dictionary<string,List<string>> where you can bind the key to ComboBox?

Comment: I have tried, it is not working.. I need exact answer

Answer (score 0):

Your error is at the following lines:

```
if(combobox.SelectedIndex == 0)
  combobox.ItemsSource = listView;
else
  combobox.ItemsSource = listView12;
```

You are setting the content of your lists as the `ItemsSource` for the combobox. It means that the options in the combobox will be the items from `listView` or `listView12`.

You shouldn't have anything to do since you already have populated your combobox during startup with the following lines:

```
combobox.Items.Add(listView);
combobox.Items.Add(listView12);
```

when the combobox selection change, you probably just want to retrieve the selected item and update some other parts of your app with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView = new ListView();
ObservableCollection<String> list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
list.Add("1");
list.Add("2");      
listView.ItemsSource = list;

listView2 = new ListView();
ObservableCollection<String> list12 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
list12.Add("11");
list12.Add("12");
listView2.ItemsSource = list12;

Dictionary<string,ObservableCollection<String>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,ObservableCollection<String>();
dictionary.Add(nameof(list), list);
dictionary.Add(nameof(list12),list12);

combobox.ItemsSource = dictionary;
//And make sure you add DisplayMemberPath="Key" in the combobox.

private void combobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   var combobox = sender as ComboBox;
   if(combobox.SelectedIndex == 0)
      combobox.ItemsSource = dictionary[nameof(list)];
   else
      combobox.ItemsSource = dictionary[nameof(list12)];

   //Clear the DisplayMemberPath since you're binding the values now.
   combobox.DisplayMemberPath  = null;
}
```

I guess this is what you are trying to achieve, though it does not make much sense.